# How Convert A List Of Model In C# To javascript Array In Razor Component [Blazor]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

i have a list of a model in C# , For Using This , I Need To Pass It To JavaScripts and using it as javascript array  , In Asp.net Core Razor Pages Or MVC
, For Converting Such a Thing I Use

```
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(dataArray));
```

but in Blazor , We Don't Have Html.Raw , And Any Resourse i Find Say How Convert A Simple Text , Not A List Of Model Or Similar Thing

Now I Want To Know How Convert A List Of A Model To JavaScript Array In Razor Components

I Try Using

```
        var data = @System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(BarChartStringDecimalModels);
```

```
     data = data.Replace("\\n", "").Replace("\\", "");
        data = JSON.parse(data);
```

but always Get Error [Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence]

Comment: Your controller can convert it by doing something like this:  JsonResult myJson =  new JsonResult(yourModel);

Comment: in my senario , i can't do this , the component get value from [parameter] from outside of components , so there is not any controller

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data to the JavaScript function, you need either:

- `IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync` (with returning value from JS)
- `IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync` (without returning a value from JS)

method.

```cs
[Inject]
IJSRuntime _jsRuntime { get; set; }
```

```cs
await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("yourComponent.action", BarChartStringDecimalModels);
```

```js
window.yourComponent = {
    action: (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        // Implementation
    }
};
```

Replace `yourComponent` with your actual component name for better reference and categorize the JS methods that the component (may) invoke.

Replace `action` with your actual JS function name.

Reference: [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0)